# Conditional / Optional where statement

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, where-clause

I have a stored procedures and a few boolean variables (`Bit`).
I want to put a `WHERE` statement if a certain variables is False.

I know I could do something like this :

```
IF (@myBoolean = 1)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM myTable
END
ELSE
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTable.Foo = 'Bar'
```

Is there a way to make the `WHERE` statement optionnal ? Because I have so many boolean variable I don't want to have a different query for each possibilities. 
This is what I have in mind (I know it does not work) :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
CASE WHEN @myBoolean = 0 
THEN WHERE myTable.Foo = 'Bar'
ELSE --Do nothing
```

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE @myBoolean = 1 or (myTable.Foo = 'Bar' and @myBoolean = 0)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
where ( @myboolean = 1 and foo = 'bar' ) or @myboolean = 0
```

Comment: Let's say this is myBool is false. You query will do `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE @myBoolean = 0` but @myBool is not part of the table won't this throw an exception ??

Comment: try it and see what it does !

Comment: Just did and realise at the same time that... 

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE TRUE`

-_- ' thanks